# detection of deleted source files in incremental builds - how?

Tags: visual-studio, incredibuild

How can an incremental build using IncrediBuild detect when a source file has been deleted?

When I modify a source file it will be recompiled and the corresponding dll relinked -- but deleting the same file does nothing, even when a complete rebuild would fail. How can IncrediBuild be instructed to check for deleted files?

**UPDATE**
I understand that Visual Studio behaves the same way, so it is not really a bug of IncrediBuild. Nonetheless I seek to remedy this situation in a Good Way. Considering that the files being deleted are known, perhaps it is possible to implement a script that removes the corresponding object files or similar. Or perhaps there is a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Modifying a source file and deleting a source file are two different things.
The scenario you are describing is a proper incremental build behavior and you will see the same behavior when building with Visual Studio (without IncrediBuild). When deleting a file and then performing an incremental build, a link step will be executed by the build system and fail whether you are using IncrediBuild or regular Visual Studio builds.

Comment: I find your answer confusing: how are modifying and deleting a file so terribly different, that one warrents rebuilding the corresponding object file and the other not? 
Also what I observe directly contradicts your last sentence. Can you clarify?